# Plugin not found error during mvn release:perform

Tags: maven-plugin, maven-release-plugin, cobertura, build-error

I am trying to do a mvn release:perform on my project and get the error pasted below.

I do not have any dependency mentioned anywhere in the project for org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin neither it is in the maven settings.xml file but still it creeps up from somewhere. Just to mention I can successfully build the project with mvn clean compile install and the mvn release:prepare command run successfully.

Can someone please help and let me know how I can get rid of this error.

```
ERROR
=====
[INFO] [ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] The plugin 'org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin' does not exist or no valid version could be found
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Total time: 13 seconds
[INFO] [INFO] Finished at: Wed Aug 15 17:03:36 BST 2012
[INFO] [INFO] Final Memory: 28M/51M
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1' at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:284) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)  at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1' at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PerformReleaseMojo.execute(PerformReleaseMojo.java:133)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)  ... 17 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.release.ReleaseExecutionException: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1' at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRunGoalsPhase.execute(AbstractRunGoalsPhase.java:89) at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.RunPerformGoalsPhase.execute(RunPerformGoalsPhase.java:67) at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.perform(DefaultReleaseManager.java:334)  at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.perform(DefaultReleaseManager.java:282)  at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.perform(DefaultReleaseManager.java:262)  at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PerformReleaseMojo.execute(PerformReleaseMojo.java:129)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.MavenExecutorException: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1' at org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.InvokerMavenExecutor.executeGoals(InvokerMavenExecutor.java:375) at org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.InvokerMavenExecutor.executeGoals(InvokerMavenExecutor.java:393) at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRunGoalsPhase.execute(AbstractRunGoalsPhase.java:81)  ... 24 more
```

Answer (score 1):

What does your pom.xml say? it should have the following in it:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <tagBase>https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/maven/components/releases</tagBase>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```